# Laravel file upload storage link working but public link is not

Tags: laravel

This is in Nova but I think the issue is with how I've setup the filesystem. But just for the full context: I use the Nova `Image` field to upload an image.

In my `config/filesystems`:

```
'blog' => [
  'driver' => 'local',
  'root' => storage_path('app/public/blog'),
  'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage/blog',
  'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

The file is uploaded correctly and a preview shows in Nova, both locally and on production. The preview uses the URL `example.com/storage/blog/filename.jpg`.

On the front-end I use `asset('blog/'.$post->image)` to display the image. The URL generated is `example.com/blog/filename.jpg`.

The weird thing is that this last URL works locally, but not on a production server (gives a 404). Does this have to do with folder/file permissions?

I have ran `php artisan storage:link` and on the server I can actually see the file both in `app/public/blog` and in `public/storage/blog`.